# Can I jump like this?

Tags: perl

In my nested `for` loops below, it is sometimes necessary to exit the outer loop and then continue program execution. Since loop labels and other goto-like constructions are heavily discouraged, I'm a bit afraid of raptors. Is this usage OK? Is there a better way to structure the program?

```
my @objects = load_objects();
OUTER: for my $obj ( @objects ) {
    for my $element ( @{$obj->elements} ) {
        if ( is_case_1( $element ) ) {
            ...
        } elsif ( is_case_2( $element ) ) {
            ...
        } else {
            warn "invalid element: $element";
            last OUTER;
        }
        stuff_that_assumes_valid_element( $element );
    }
    stuff_that_assumes_valid_object( $obj );
}
store_objects( @objects );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two comments to make.  The first addresses the use of labels.  The second is on why you you might want an exception rather than a logical test.

### Loop Labels

Loop labels and loop control are the one common form of `goto` that isn't generally frowned upon.  (The other form is the rare use of a particular form in AUTOLOADER to seamlessly transfer control to generated code--unless you start experimenting with deeper magics you will never need it.)

`@rassie`'s point that your tests should be encapsulated in an `is_valid()` method for your objects is excellent, but I want to comment on another important aspect of using labeled loops: **naming**.

Using `OUTER` as a label is like using `%hash` as a variable.  The name tells a maintenance programmer nothing about what is happening or why.

Perl syntax calls out for a noun-verb naming structure for labels with keywords like `next` and `last`.   Good names for your outer loop could be `OBJECT_TEST`, `OBJECT_VALIDATION`, or `OBJECT_CHECK`.

### Exceptions

When I look at your code I see a structure that is focussed on the normal case. This is fine as long as you have a way to ensure that errors are caught.

If your `stuff_that_assumes_valid_object()` method checks for validity, then throws an exception (via `die`), then your code becomes very simple.

This code is identical to your nested loop:

```
 eval { $_->stuff_that_dies_on_invalid_object() for @objects }; 
 store_objects(@objects);
```

But if you want the behavior in `@rassie`'s code of filtering out invalid objects and only storing the valid ones, you can do:

```
my @to_store = grep {
    eval { $_->stuff_that_dies_on_invalid_object; 1 }
} @objects;
store_objects(@to_store);
```

It's also nice to know that your calls to code that makes assumptions will be safe.  Either you expect a failure and catch the exception, or your program terminates on an unexpected, unsafe operation.

P.S. `@rassie` is absolutely right about the Law of Demeter.  Keep your object internals and knowledge about them as limited as possible.  Consider making `store_objects()`, `assumes_valid_elements()` and `assumes_valid_objects()` code into methods.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the code is OK, i.e. I don't think it must be changed. However, to increase clarity, I would do a couple of things differently:

It's probably better to write an `is_valid()` method for your objects, so that whole inner loop is a single function call. Then, you can use `grep` to shorten the outer loop like this:

```
    my @objects = load_objects();
    my @valid_objects = grep { $_->is_valid() } @objects;
    stuff_that_assumes_valid_object($_) for @valid_objects;
    store_objects(@valid_objects);
```

Also, depending on what `stuff_that_assumes_valid_element` does, you can either put that call into `is_valid()` or into `stuff_that_assumes_valid_object`. Either way, your top-level code works with objects and thus shouldn't know too much about single elements inside those objects, that's something the object itself should know and do (see [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) for reasoning).